# Как правильно обрабатывать исключения при работе с БД?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net, ado.net

У меня есть в data access layer метод, который записывает значение в определенное поле для данного id. Мне сказали, что ты не обрабатываешь, а глушишь исключения. Как правильно нужно делать? Стоит ли вообще оборачивать подобные конструкции в try-catch? И будет ли считаться нормальным тоном, если при ошибке выбрасывать новое исключение с каким-либо сообщением?

```
public bool SetField(string table, string field, int id, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = string.Format("update [{0}] set {1} = @value where id = @id;", table, field);
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Правильно сказали. Функция пообещала установить значение, а не сделала. И что должна вызывающая функция делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что bool вам не скажет, что же произошло при `update` таблицы `table`, (и можно долго ходить и заваривать кофе...и гадать потом на гуще)  для того что бы это узнать надо в секции:

```
catch (SqlException)
{
    return false;
}
```

либо "прокинуть" `throw` исключение дальше и обработать(с выводом сообщения об ошибке) его в месте вызова

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

либо обработать есть в этом месте, например так:

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    return false;
}
```

либо сгенерировать своё исключение(ситуация вполне нормальная):

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    throw new MyException(ex.Message, "АпдейтНеАпдейт");
}
```

> Как правильно нужно делать?

Вопрос задачи.

> Стоит ли вообще оборачивать подобные конструкции в try-catch?

Конечно стоит. При таких операциях большая вероятность возникновения исключений.

> И будет ли считаться нормальным тоном, если при ошибке выбрасывать
>   новое исключение с каким-либо сообщением?

Конечно.